# capture header level changes - oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How to capture header level changes . In my case  I need to check if there is any change happened in the header shipping method.

I tried when-validate-record

**IF event_name = 'WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD'
    THEN
        IF (form_name = 'OEXOEORD' AND block_name = 'ORDER')**
Actually I dont want to use this 'When-validate-record' or when-validate_item.
Please help is there any other way .

Comment: what is header shipping method? It is probably something specific to Oracle EBS?

Comment: Yes correct.... EBS  :)

Comment: and what's the use case? When do you need to refresh data? I mean from user point of view

Comment: Hi Peter,  that issue we resolved actually by adding an FP 
Trigger Event : When-New-Block Instance
Trigger Object : Line
Condition : some condition
 Processing Mode : Not in Enter Query Mode
Type: Builtin
Builtin_type: DO_KEY
Argument: EXECUTE_QUERY

Now the straight forward scenario is working fine.

Comment: Now a new issue came up with one scenario.
If the user changes shipping method (unintentionally) and trying to close the form. in this case the new shipping method should not get saved.
in other words, if the user tries to close the form  , my procedure inside when-validate-record should not call. Kindly help if you could.